# Enable Document to PDF converter when using Nextcloud docker image

Tags: docker, pdf, nextcloud

I can't get Document to PDF Converter app to work on a Nextcloud installation using docker and docker-compose

I'm setting up Nextcloud at home using docker images. So far I've managed to run Nextcloud successfully following this tutorial: https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/installing-nextcloud-docker/

What I'm trying now, is to enable the Document to PDF Converter app:

- I installed and enabled it using Nextcloud web interface
- I set up rules to match all libreoffice MIME types (the same rules I used to add tags against the libreoffice files, and tags are working, so I assume the rules are good)
- I (manually) installed libreoffice inside the docker container of Nextcloud
- I added:

```
  'preview_office_cl_parameters' =>
    ' --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --invisible --norestore '.
    '--convert-to png --outdir ',
  'preview_libreoffice_path' => '/usr/bin/libreoffice',
```

to `config.php`

- I restarted all the containers

But I see no pdf created when I create/update a libreoffice document.

To test it, I created an odt document on my pc and let the nextcloud desktop client sync it with the server. The file is uploaded (and updated if I modify it) but no pdf has been created.

Is there anyone who configured pdf conversion in this scenario, or can you help me to find some clue?

Thanks.